# Webservices client and ssl

Tags: java, web-services, ssl, client

I have a Java client that calls a web service at the moment using the Http protocol.
When i try to use the Https protocol i keep getting this error
java.io.IOException: DerInputStream.getLength(): lengthTag=127, too big.

Any ideas what could be up?
Thanks
Damien

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to american export regulations in encryption technologies, you can't use strong encryption out of the box. Your error looks like you (or your framework) is trying to use strong encryption, and other parts of the framework is not allowing it.

A discussion of a case that looks similar to yours can be found [here](http://www.codecomments.com/archive253-2004-4-173117.html).
A good crypto provider is [BouncyCastle](http://www.bouncycastle.org/java.html). Takes some reading, but it's not that hard to make it work.

Good luck,

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are connecting your HTTPS client to the server port that talks over HTTPS (TLS/SSL) rather than HTTP?

Answer (score 0):

YOu have to pass the keystore type from the client. This error should go then.